# Inserting items to UnitofWork Repository - objects not saving - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, unit-of-work

I'm having a problem with the insertion code of a particular object or technically objects as I am looking to submit an image object and then a "KitchenItem" which is derived from a "Post" object that contains basic id, description strings.

I have implemented the generic repository from the ASP.Net tutorials and this is working for other elements of the site.

Image Object:

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string AltText { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    private DateTime? createdDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get { return createdDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow; }
        set { createdDate = value; }
    }
}
```

KitchenItem   (I'm aware that I'm repeating code with the images, I want to attach particular images to elements within my site and the multiple uploads weren't achieving what I wanted to do... off topic though I'm open to suggestions for cleaner code)

```
  public class KitchenItem:Post
  {

    public Image MainSlider { get; set; }

    public Image MainSlider2 { get; set; }

    public Image MainSlider3 { get; set; }

    public Image MainSlider4 { get; set; }

    public Image MainSlider5 { get; set; }

    public Image SideImage1 { get; set; }

    public Image SideImage2 { get; set; }

  }
```

}

View Model:

```
  public class CreateProjectViewModel
  {
    public KitchenItem  KitchenItem { get; set; }


    public HttpPostedFileBase MainSlider1 { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase MainSlider2 { get; set; }

     public HttpPostedFileBase MainSlider3 { get; set; }

     public HttpPostedFileBase MainSlider4 { get; set; }

     public HttpPostedFileBase MainSlider5 { get; set; }

     public HttpPostedFileBase SideImage { get; set; }

     public HttpPostedFileBase SideImage2 { get; set; }
}
```

Create function in controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create( CreateProjectViewModel viewModel)
    {
        KitchenItem model = new KitchenItem();
        model = viewModel.KitchenItem;
        try
        {


                 // handle image uploads manually
                    if(viewModel.MainSlider1!=null){
                        model.MainSlider = AddImage(viewModel.MainSlider1, model.MainSlider);
                    }
                if(viewModel.MainSlider2!=null){
                    model.MainSlider2 = AddImage(viewModel.MainSlider2, model.MainSlider2);
                    }
                if( viewModel.MainSlider3!=null){
                    model.MainSlider3 = AddImage(viewModel.MainSlider3, model.MainSlider3);
                    }
                if(viewModel.MainSlider4!=null){
                    model.MainSlider4 = AddImage(viewModel.MainSlider4, model.MainSlider4);
                    }
                 if(viewModel.MainSlider5!=null){
                    model.MainSlider5 = AddImage(viewModel.MainSlider5, model.MainSlider5);
                    }
               if(viewModel.SideImage!=null){
                   model.SideImage1 = AddImage(viewModel.SideImage, model.SideImage1);
               }
                if(viewModel.SideImage2!=null)
                {
                    model.SideImage2 = AddImage(viewModel.SideImage2, model.SideImage2);
                }



                //Log date posted
                model.PostedOn = DateTime.Now;

                model.Category = unitofWork.CategoryRepository.GetByID(model.CategoryID);
                //create post
                unitofWork.KitchenItemRepository.Insert(model);
                unitofWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch (DataException dex )
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.Image files not saved and Kitchen Item not Updated");
        }
        PopulateCategoriesDropDownList();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Add image function:

```
 public Image AddImage(HttpPostedFileBase imageToSave, Image modelImage)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img = modelImage;
        img.ImageUrl=SaveUploadedFile(imageToSave, img.Id);
        unitofWork.ImagesRepository.Insert(img);
        return img;
    }
```

I've tracked the operation using break points and the AddImage function works and passing back the image successfully to Create() - Similarly the model within Create() shows that it contains all expected content right up until the unitofwork.kitchenItem.Insert(model);

A couple of thoughts I have had are that it has something to do with the relational element of the functions, all of the image id's initiate as 0... although I would have assumed that the db insert would have handled this?

Generic Repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal GlenlithContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(GlenlithContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

}

Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context()
        : base("Context")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KitchenItem> KitchenItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();




        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasOptional(c=>c.Category);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasOptional(c => c.Tags);



        modelBuilder.Entity<KitchenItem>()
            .Map(m =>
          m.ToTable("KitchenItems"));

       modelBuilder.Entity<KitchenItem>().HasOptional(c => c.Category);
        modelBuilder.Entity<KitchenItem>().HasOptional(c => c.Tags);
        modelBuilder.Entity<KitchenItem>().HasMany(c => c.MainSliderPath);


    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Glenlith.ViewModels.CreateProjectViewModel


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";


 }
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js">        </script>
<style>
    .imagePreview {
        width: 870px;
       height: 420px;
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     display: inline-block;
    }
    .sideImagePreview {
    width: 270px;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     display: inline-block;
 }

</style>
<div class=" row">
<h2>Create Kitchen Project</h2>
</div>


<div class=" row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "KitchenItems", FormMethod.Post, new { EncType =     "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class=" row">
 <div class=" col-md-12">


    <div id="tabs">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Main Slider 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Main Slider 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Main Slider 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Main Slider 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Main Slider 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-6">Side Image 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-7">Side Image 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.Title, htmlAttributes:  new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="imagePreview" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Images for the Main Slider should be saved as 870px by 420px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainSlider1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainSlider1, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainSlider1,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>


        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider2.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider2.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider2.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider2.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider2.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="imagePreview2" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Images for the Main Slider should be saved as 870px by 420px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainSlider2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainSlider2, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile2" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainSlider2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider3.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider3.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider3.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider3.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider3.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider3.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="imagePreview3" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Images for the Main Slider should be saved as 870px by 420px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainSlider3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainSlider3, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile3" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainSlider3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider4.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider4.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider4.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider4.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider4.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider4.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="imagePreview4" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Images for the Main Slider should be saved as 870px by 420px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainSlider4, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainSlider4, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile4" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainSlider4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider5.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider5.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider5.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider5.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider5.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.MainSlider5.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="imagePreview5" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Images for the Main Slider should be saved as 870px by 420px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainSlider5, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainSlider5, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile5" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainSlider5, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage1.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage1.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage1.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage1.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage1.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage1.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>



            <div id="imagePreview6" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Side Images should be saved as 270px by 200px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SideImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SideImage, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile6" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SideImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage2.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage2.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage2.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage2.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage2.AltText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.SideImage2.AltText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="imagePreview7" class=" imagePreview"></div>
            Side Images should be saved as 270px by 200px
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SideImage2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SideImage2, new { type = "file", id = "uploadFile7" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SideImage2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
        <div class=" col-md-4">

         <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Title, htmlAttributes: new {    @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.ShortDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.ShortDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.ShortDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Meta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Meta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Meta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.UrlSlug, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.UrlSlug, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.UrlSlug, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Published, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Published)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.Published, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KitchenItem.CategoryID, "Category")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KitchenItem.CategoryID)
            </div>




        </div>
        <div class=" row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</div>




<style type="text/css">
    .dz-max-files-reached {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    //File Upload response from the server
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
        maxFiles: 10,
        init: function () {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (data) {
                var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');

            });
        }
    };


</script>

<script>
 $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
 });


     </script>

<script src="~/js/sliderUpload.js"></script>
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated I'm relatively new to MVC and am keen to build clean code and I know that getting my head around mapping and handling the database is the biggest hurdle for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Image AddImage(HttpPostedFileBase imageToSave, Image modelImage)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img = modelImage;
        img.ImageUrl=SaveUploadedFile(imageToSave, img.Id);
        unitofWork.ImagesRepository.Insert(img);

        unitOfWork.SaveChanges(); // you didn't save the change.

        return img;
    }
```

you didn't save the change, Unit Of Work will not persist the insert operation because of that. check the code above. In unit of work you should have Save() or SaveChanges() method that wrap DbContext.SaveChanges() to persist your changes.

Comment: Thanks Larry, I just amended that code, unfortunately that hasn't added the Image to the details when I check the server explorer(it does save the actual image to the target folder though as the SaveUploadedFile works).

Comment: then you have problem in the views. can you update your question with the views code? btw, you only asked why objects not saving.

Comment: Sure, should be updated now. Apologies if I didn't communicate the issue, just to clarify.... it is that the items aren't being submitted to the database... that includes both the image and the "kitchenpost" everything else seems to be working from what I can see